# RDBMS Schema design - should I separate the tables or not in order to capture new attribute?

Tags: ms-access, database-design, database-schema, rdbms

I have these two tables now:

1)

```
      Models
id (PK)    desc    ...
```

2)

```
            Model_Hierarchy
parent_id (PK)    child_id (PK)    qty
```

This represents a basic structure of production assembly. For example Model id = 001, desc = "shoeA" can consist of 2 other models:

1) model id = 002, desc = "upperA"
2) model id = 003, desc = "soleA"

and the relationship would be simply represented in the hierarchy table as follows:

```
            Model_Hierarchy
parent_id (PK)    child_id (PK)    qty
001               002              1
001               003              1
```

So in my application it would look like:

```
name             qty
shoeA---
       -upperA   1
       -soleA    1
```

This works for now. However, now I found out that for some specific model relationships I also have to catch attribute `size`. For example, I have a model `cuttingKniveA` and I would like to capture something like:

```
name            size  area (cm^2)
cuttingKniveA   35    12.4
                36    12.9
                37    13.6
                38    13.6 *note
                .     .
                .     .
```

**HOWEVER** *note: I must be able to capture the fact that for some sizes, same knive can be used. So for example for size 38 the same knive is used as for size 37! This is the part that I struggle with and I'm not sure how to represent it in my RDBMS.

There are several ways to do this and I'm not sure which one to pick (the most efficient / clear for future development).

### First approach:

In `Models` table:

```
id(PK)    desc
1         cuttingKniveA
2         35
3         36
4         37
```

In `Model_Hierarchy` table:

```
parent_id (PK)    child_id (PK)    qty
1                 2                12.4
1                 3                12.9
1                 4                13.6
```

How would I catch the fact that `size` 38 uses the knive with `size` 37? Ie. `model_id` 4.

### Second approach:

In `Models` table:

```
id(PK)    desc
1         cuttingKniveA
2         ""
3         ""
4         ""
```

In `Model_Hierarchy` table:

extend by adding `size` attribute.

```
parent_id (PK)    child_id (PK)    size    qty
1                 2                35      12.4
1                 3                36      12.9
1                 4                37      13.6
```

Here it might be easier to capture that size 38 uses same knive, yet I don't like such solution. Ie:

```
parent_id (PK)    child_id (PK)    size    qty
1                 4                38      13.6
```

There are 2 big problems here:
1) Keeping `qty` consistent (ie. even though size 37 and 38 are the same `child_id` of 4, they are 2 records and so a change to 1 must change the qty of the other too.
2) As of now it validates the primary key condition, ie. unique `parent_id`, `child_id` pairing. This complicates things as capturing this relation is a small subset of all relations shown in `Model_Hierarchy` and so I could add `size` attribute for this small subset, but I would rather not make a major change to the table such as changing the PK.

### Third approach:

Create a new table to capture the `size` relationship, ie.

```
parent_id (PK)    child_id (PK)    size (PK)    qty
1                 2                35           12.4
1                 3                36           12.9
1                 4                37           13.6
1                 4                38           13.6
```

There is two problems I see:
1) Same problem with keeping the `qty` consistent as in the **Second approach**, ie. if 13.6 changes it should change in both records.
2) Now I have a new table that captures extremely similar structure as a table I already have (ie. parent - child - qty).

Is there some other easier way to do it that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it properly, knife size is a property of the knife, not a property of the hierarchy - so IMO it belongs in the part table that describes knife.  Size 37 and size 38 are 2 different knife codes, I think.   In the hierarchy table, you need some logic that defines alternate parts, to show that in some particular assembly, either knife could be used.  You might try a dummy part, with the definition of that part showing the 2 optional sizes that could be used.  In any case, there's more than the data structure involved - you need some logic that allows for OR conditions in the hierarchy table, rather than just the AND condition that is normally used.

Answer (score 0):

Having some trouble understanding your explanation.  Hopefully I've included everything you need and it's understandable if a little long

Would this design work:

## Domains

(**note**: Domains are basically the data types you'll be using - fields created on the same domain can be used to join tables)
**IdentifierOfShoeModel** - integer
**IdentifierOfSubModel** - integer
**IdentifierOfKnife** - integer
**IdentifierOfShoeSize** - integer
**DescriptionOfShoeModel** - string
**DescriptionOfSubModel** - string
**DescriptionOfKnife** - string
**ShoeSize** - double
**ShoeArea** - double
**SubModelQty** - integer

## Table: Model

**ID** - IdentifierOfShoeModel
**Desc** - DescriptionOfShoeModel
**Primary Key** ID

## Table: Knife

**ID** - IdentifierOfKnife
**Desc** - DescriptionOfKnife
**Primary Key** ID

## Table: SubModel

**ID** - IdentifierOfSubModel
**ModelID**  - IdentifierOfShoeModel
**Desc** - DescriptionOfSubModel
**Primary Key** ID
**Foreign Key** ModelID **references** Model

## Table: Size

**ID** - IdentifierOfShoeSize
**KnifeID** - IdentifierOfKnife
**Size** - ShoeSize
**Area** - ShoeArea
**Primary Key** ID
**Foreign Key** KnifeID **references** Knife

## Table: Cutting

**ShoeID** - IdentifierOfShoeModel
**SizeID** - IdentifierOfShoeSize
**Primary Key** (ShoeID, SizeID)
**Foreign Key** ShoeID **references** Model
**Foreign Key** SizeID **references** Size

With these entries in the tables:

**Model**

```
ID  Desc  
1   ShoeA
```

**Knife**

```
ID  Desc
1   cuttingKnifeA
```

**SubModel**

```
ID  ModelID Desc
1   1       upperA
2   1       soleA
```

**Size**

```
ID  KnifeID Size    Area
1   1       35      12.4
2   1       36      12.9
3   1       37      13.6
4   1       38      13.6
```

**Cutting**

```
ShoeID  SizeID
1       1
```

Use this query to get the results in the bottom table:

```
SELECT      Model.Desc, 
            SubModel.Desc, 
            Knife.Desc, 
            Size.Size, 
            Size.Area
FROM        (((
                Cutting INNER JOIN Model ON Cutting.ShoeID = Model.ID) 
                        INNER JOIN [Size] ON Cutting.SizeID = Size.ID) 
                        INNER JOIN Knife ON Size.KnifeID = Knife.ID) 
                        INNER JOIN SubModel ON Model.ID = SubModel.ModelID
ORDER BY    Model.Desc, 
            Knife.Desc  


Model.Desc  SubModel.Desc   Knife.Desc      Size    Area
ShoeA       soleA           cuttingKnifeA   38      13.6
ShoeA       upperA          cuttingKnifeA   38      13.6
ShoeA       soleA           cuttingKnifeA   35      12.4
ShoeA       upperA          cuttingKnifeA   35      12.4
```

Comment: The problem is that the hierarchy has unknown depth and basically a 'Shoe' might not be the final product either. For instance, a shoe can be packed in a package that consists of multiple shoes... each of these shoes consists of sub parts and each subpart can consist of more subparts and/or material etc etc etc. I didn't want to explain the whole domain fully otherwise the question would be just way too long. The specific problem is capturing the fact that 1 cutting knife can accommodate multiple sizes.